# Exception filling buffer with data from underlying input stream

Tags: ajax, jsp, tomcat, file-upload

When I upload a file using Apache Commons FileUpload, it throws an exception:

> org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Exception filling buffer with data from underlying input stream: not an EAGAIN status, so perhaps disconnected client?

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: 'var form = document.forms[0];
     form.submit();                       window.parent.frames["upload"].location="button.jsp";'

Comment: What version of tomcat are you on?

Comment: How is the `[ajax]` tag relevant to this question? Are you attempting to upload files by ajax? This requires a very special approach. The chance is big that you did something wrong there.  You'd like to confirm for yourself first that it works with a basic form without any line of JavaScript code. If it works, then you're going to need to show an SSCCE of your failed ajax attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this thread](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Java/comp.lang.java.programmer/2007-07/msg02444.html)
there is a [bug](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40960) reported with tomcat-5.5.x, that was resolved in 6.x.

Not a smoking gun answer, but worth checking out.

Comment: I got it ! I'm very glad you can answer my question! Thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome.  If you could accept this answer, I'd be greatfull -- and we both get credit!

Comment: Yes! I`ve accepted your answer! I`ve dealed with it in another way ! Thanks again !